# Partial view not rendering with asynch request for update

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, asynchronous, partial-views

---

### My objective

---

is to make an asynchronous call in my jquery file(**otf.js**) that updates my restaurant list in my home page (**index.cshtml**) with a Search term entered in the form that filters the restaurant results.  **otf.js** is in a bundle, and is rendered in the layout view.

---

### My Problem

---

is that I enter a search term and submit my form, and the list updates as expected, but when entering a new search term and clicking submit, the list does not change.  It needs to change every time I enter a new search result and click submit.

---

### My source code

### otf.js

---

```
$(function () {

    var ajaxFormSubmit = function () {
        var $form = $(this);

        var options = {
            url: $form.attr("action"),
            type: $form.attr("method"),
            data: $form.serialize()
        };

        $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
            var $target = $($form.attr("data-otf-target"));
            $target.replaceWith(data);
        });

        return false;
    };

    $("form[data-otf-ajax='true']").submit(ajaxFormSubmit);
});
```

---

### index.cshtml

---

```
@model IEnumerable<OdeToFood.Models.RestaurantListViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<hr />

<form method="get" action="@Url.Action("index")"
        data-otf-ajax="true" data-otf-target="#restaurantList">
    <input type="search" name="searchTerm" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search By Name" />
</form>

<div id="restaurantList">
    @Html.Partial("_Restaurants", Model)
</div>
```

---

### _Restaurants.cshtml (a partial view)

---

```
@model IEnumerable<OdeToFood.Models.RestaurantListViewModel>

   @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div>
            <h4>@item.Name</h4>
            <div>
                @item.City, @item.Country

            </div>
            <div>
                Reviews: @item.CountOfReviews

            </div>
            <hr />

        </div>
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `<div id="restaurantList">` is wrapping around the `@Html.Partial("_Restaurants", Model)` line in **index.cshtml**, and it needs to be wrapped around the `@foreach` code block in the partial view **_Restaurants.cshtml**

I made this change to my code, and presto, the restaurant list was updated every time i clicked the search button, not just the first time.

Now the only question is why does this cause the list not to update after the first time?

Comment: Is it a question or an answer or both?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are removing form from DOM to be replaced by new form. In this case, you should  delegate event.

So:

```
$("form[data-otf-ajax='true']").submit(ajaxFormSubmit);
```

Become:  { here i use document as delegate, but better is to use closest static container of the form }

```
$(document).on('submit',"form[data-otf-ajax='true']",ajaxFormSubmit);
```