# render partial view from jquery not working

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, asynchronous, partial-views

I have some issues with rendering a partial view using jquery. Even if it was asked more than once ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901233/partial-view-not-rendering-with-asynch-request-for-update)), I didn't found a solution that worked for me:
My view:

```
@model IEnumerable<OdeToFood.Models.RestaurantListViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<form method="get" action="@Url.Action("Index")" data-otf-ajax="true" data-otf-target="#restaurantlist">
    <input type="search" name="searchTerm" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search By Name" />

</form>

@Html.Partial("_Restaurants", Model)
```

My partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<OdeToFood.Models.RestaurantListViewModel>

<div id="restaurantList">

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div>
            <h4>@item.Name</h4>
            <div>@item.City, @item.Country</div>
            <div>REviews: @item.CountOfReviews</div>
            <hr />
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

otf.js:

```
$(function () {

    var ajaxFormSubmit = function () {
        var $form = $(this);

        var options = {
            url: $form.attr("action"),
            type: $form.attr("method"),
            data: $form.serialize()
        };

        $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
            var $target = $($form.attr("data-otf-target"));
            $target.replaceWith(data);
        });

        return false;
    };

    $("form[data-otf-ajax='true']").submit(ajaxFormSubmit);
});
```

index action of my controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index(string searchTerm = null)
        {
            var model =
                _db.Restaurants
                .OrderByDescending(r => r.RestaurantReviews.Average(a => a.Rating))                
                .Where(r => searchTerm == null || r.Name.StartsWith(searchTerm))
                .Select(r => new RestaurantListViewModel
                {
                    Id = r.Id,
                    Name = r.Name,
                    City = r.City,
                    Country = r.Country,
                    CountOfReviews = r.RestaurantReviews.Count()
                }
                )
                .Take(10);

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return PartialView("_Restaurants", model);
            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

My issue is that nothing happens when I press search button. I've added an test alert like:

```
$.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
            var $target = $($form.attr("data-otf-target"));
            alert('test');
            $target.replaceWith(data);
        });
```

and the alert showed when I've clicked the search button, but in site nothing happens. Anyone knows what is my issue?

Comment: Any errors in browser console?

Comment: no errors, just a warning:The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `#restaurantlist` as the target, whereas div id is actually `restaurantList`. Capital "L".